# PHP GD ellipse generating strange shape

Tags: php, gd, ellipse

I have a problem with PHP GD imageellipse function.
With this code:

```
$im = imagecreate(4000,4000);

$bianco = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$nero = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

imageellipse($im, 2000, 2000, $d, $d, $nero);
```

When $d (diameter) is smaller than "2000" the circle is normal
[circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okvDD.png)
But if I use a bigger $d the "circle" is like that:
[strange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mmHV.png)

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I see the same problem in PHP 7.x above 2000px diameter. Looks like a bug (or limitation) in PHP/GD.